# Search optimization for text pattern

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a table which has millions of rows pertaining to website form data. I'm trying to find key characters "5890". What is the best way to optimally fetch the results.

Can I use anything else besides regexp

```
SELECT * FROM FORMS F
WHERE (REGEXP_LIKE(lower(f."Text Pane"),'5890'));
```

Comment: If the query is run regularly and you want to avoid the full table scan then you can create a function based index and see how the query performance.

Comment: Have a look at Oracle Text indexes if you want to be able to search for fragments of text efficiently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use normal `like` and without `lower` function as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM FORMS F
WHERE f."Text Pane" LIKE '%5890%';
```

`REGEXP_LIKE` and `LOWER` are costly and not needed in your query.

Comment: Unfortunately, the real problem is that Oracle has to check every row in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `INSTR`:

```
SELECT * FROM FORMS F
WHERE INSTR(f."Text Pane",'5890') > 0;
```

I'm not sure if this would be significantly different from Tejash's answer using `LIKE`. Oracle will still have to do a full table scan and hit every row in the table.